# grep a certain format, is this possible?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'm trying to find a certain unknown 11 character sequence in a huge packet capture file. The one thing I do know is that the string I'm looking has format `x.x-xxxxxxx`. I've been looking for a while and cannot find the right grep statement to accomplish this, can anyone help?

Comment: What do the `x`s stand for - any character at all?

Comment: yeah any character letters or numbers

Comment: OK, so alpha numeric - only `a` through `z`, `A` through `Z` and `0` through `9` ?

Comment: yes sir! the string cannot contain anything other than alpha numeric characters

Comment: You have regex as a tag, why not give it a go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format for `grep` is what we call a "POSIX regular expression" (look it up) and it support some simple matching primitives. If you know you want just alpha-numeric characters, you can use a character class like this: `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. `grep` even has a shortcut for this specific class (because it is so useful) like this: `[[:alnum:]]`. `man grep` has a lot more information about that.

You can also use repetition counting to specify how many of these characters you want to match. In your case you want to match: 1 alpha-numeric character, then a period, then one more character, then a dash followed by 7 characters. In POSIX regular expression this looks like so:

```
[[:alnum:]]\.[[:alnum:]]-[[:alnum:]]{7}
```

Notes:

1. I had to escape the period with a backslash, otherwise it will be resolved as the "catch all characters" regular expression.
2. In order for the repetition clause (the curly braces) to work you'd need to enable "extended regular expression mode" using `-e` or by running `egrep` instead of the standard `grep`.

So the full command may look like this:

```
egrep '[[:alnum:]]\.[[:alnum:]]-[[:alnum:]]{7}' /some/file
```

The output will be the lines where that expression matched, possibly highlighted in color (depending on your terminal). If your packet file is not line delimited (maybe it is binary) expect a lot of mess on the screen.

Comment: this was it. I was having trouble finding the correct regex expression for it. Thanks so much!